# Why is the " UndefVarError: undef not defined " error happened?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

It is used in the code:
`tt=Array{Int64}(undef,0)`
but the following error is shown:
`UndefVarError: undef not defined`
would you please say why it happened? and is there any alternative for the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an empty vector just write (should work in very old and new Julia):

```
tt = Int64[]
```

or even `tt = Int[]` if you are on a system with 64 bit ints (which is almost always true)

Answer (score 1):

`undef` was introduced in Julia 0.7. If you are using a lower version, update Julia.

Or you can try `tt=Array{Int64}(0)`. I don't know whether this works in your system.